# How does ARP resolve in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, arp

Interested in knowing the working of ARP in AWS. Can someone please help me in understanding it as I am new to AWS?

I have created 2 ec2 instances and did arping. I'm getting the ARP response but it is not from the ARP destination instances.

Also, is it possible to receive the broadcasted ARP request in another ec2 instance which is in the same subnet?